# Segmentation Fault with strcat()

Tags: c

I am getting a segmentation fault when trying concatenate strings. The goal of the code is to create 1000 files each with incrementing names hw7-1.data, hw7-2.data and so on until you get to hw7-999.data. It should be more trivial than I am making it, and the only reason it is segfaulting should be that the destination string is going out of bounds, but I am just not seeing it. I have a couple extra includes in I know, but besides that I cannot see why it is segfaulting on the first strcat. Any thoughts as t

The output is:

0

Here

Seg Fault

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<pthread.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<sys/stat.h>

int main(void)
{
    int x;
    char* number;
    number=malloc(10);
    char* filename;
    filename=malloc(100);
    char* end;
    end=malloc(10);
    for (x=0; x<1000; x++)
    {
        filename="./hw7-";

        sprintf(number, "%d", x);
        printf("%s\n", number);
        printf("Here \n");
        strcat(filename,"1");
        printf("Here \n");
        strcat(filename,".data");
        printf("Here \n");
        int fd2 = open(filename, O_RDWR | O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IROTH);

    }
}
```

Comment: `filename="./hw7-";` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: `filename="./hw7-";` --> `strcpy(filename, "./hw7-");`

Comment: You better use `free` after `malloc`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is caused by the line:

```
filename="./hw7-";
```

1. You have lost the initial memory that was allocated by `malloc`.
2. `filename` now points to read-only memory section of the program.

Change that line to:

```
strcpy(filename, "./hw7-");
```

**PS**

It's not clear from your post what your intentions are with `number` and `end`.

You allocate memory for `end` but I don't see `end` used anywhere after that.
You fill `number` with the call to `sprintf` but you don't use it after that.

You allocate memory with `malloc` but don't have any calls to deallocate the memory. You need to add:

```
free(end);
free(filename);
free(number);
```

before the end of `main`.

Answer (score 2):

You allocated memory

```
filename=malloc(100);
```

and now pointer filename points to the allocated memory.

But then you reassigned this pointer

```
filename="./hw7-";
```

Now it points to the string literal in the static memory. You lost the address of the previously allocated memory. As result there is a memory leak.

String literals are immutable in C and C++. So you may not use strcat with string literals and moreover strcat is trying to write beyond the string literal.

```
strcat(filename,"1");
```

You should write

```
strcpy( filename, "./hw7-" );
```

instead assignung the pointer.

Another approach is to use function `sprintf` in one line instead of several calls of string functions.

I do not think that you need to allocate memory dynamically for such a short string. You could use a character array or A variable length character array (VLA).

Comment: @Jongware Yes he could use sprintf.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is much more complicated than it needs to be. Other answers point out your errors but here is an alternative way of writing the same effect. I assume that you meant to use `number` instead of `1` each time:

```
for (int x = 0; x < 1000; ++x)
{
    char filename[100];
    sprintf(filename, "./hw7-%d.data", x);
    int fd2 = open(filename, ..........

}
```